# Symfony doctrine database normalization

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Im working on a database and I have a problem with one of my relations, I have a Person entity and an Address entity and there is a OneToMany relation between Person and Address. I want to normalize the Address entity so if you have multiple Persons with the same Address, there is only one address in the database. Here is a visualization:

> Person 1: { id: 1, name: "foo", address_id: 1 }
>
> Person 2: { id: 2, name: "bar", address_id: 1 }
>
> Address 1: { id: 1, street: "barstreet", housenumber: 123 }

If I want to change the address for Person 1 I dont want to change Address 1 because person 2 is still linked to it so I want this to happen:

> Person 1: { id: 1, name: "foo", address_id: 2 }
>
> Person 2: { id: 2, name: "bar", address_id: 1 }
>
> Address 1: { id: 1, street: "barstreet", housenumber: 123 }
>
> Address 2: { id: 1, street: "bazstreet", housenumber: 5 }

What is the best way of solving this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Same address but different house numbers?  Or is that a typo?

Comment: You have 2 possibilities, stay with your 1-n relation and then if you change the address of person1 it will change it for other users with same address. Or you can change your relation to a 1-1 relation, and then set to every persons a distinct address. If you want to do it as you said it will be a bit tricky, i'm not sure it is really efficient.

Comment: @ErwanHaquet do you mean the first example wil actualy have 2 Addresses instead of 1, one for each relation

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my question, in the second state the street of Address 1 was "bazstreet" but it must have been "barstreet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of you database looks fine. 
I suppose that you have cases with many people which are living at the same address :)

When you need to update an address of a person, I would do the next flow:

1. Check if the address with the provided street number, house etc exists in the database.
2. If that address **exists** in the **database**, we associate that person with that address.
3. If it doesn't **exist** in the **database**, a new address should be created and added to that person.

Comment: I think the question was what to do if a person changes their address which is already being used by other users.

Comment: yes, I know :) Even if the address is used by another user or not - either ways should be treated in the same place if you know what I mean....Hope I was clear :)

Comment: No actualy my question is where I should write the logic